# Lazarus: which toolkit is used?

Tags: lazarus

i would like to know which toolkit is used in Lazarus IDE (linux version) ? 
It isnt gtk ? Or maybe ... other ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple possibilties, GTK2 or QT.  Older versions also supported GTK1. There are unfinished efforts (LCL-FPGUI) to build directly on top of X11.

Most distros tend to ship the GTK2 edition though

This partially also QT requires a "flattening" library called qtinf (sometimes also called QTPAS), which wraps C++ QT in C, so it can be called by Pascal.

Answer (score 1):

No. Lazarus uses the fpGUI toolkit as its native toolkit. You can also use Qt, Carbon, Cocoa, GTK1, GTK2, I seem to remember TK, and WX widgets as possible alternatives also. [Here is a page that talks about fpGUI, and mentions some other toolkits that can be used in Lazarus also.](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/fpGUI_Interface) Cheers!